# Verify simple smart contract on etherscan

Tags: remix, etherscan, contract-verification

I'm having trouble with verification of smart contracts and some ERC20 tokens. The only tokens I was able to verify were the ones derived from ERC20Detailed. Here's a simple contract that I found on the web that also fails. I have all the settings and parameters right including compiler version, byte code, etc.

I'm using Ropsten. Before answering, please try to deploy and verify this yourself. Thanks!

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storeddata;
    function set(uint x) public {
        storeddata = x;
    }
    function get() public view returns(uint) {
        return storeddata;
    }
}
```

Comment: Deployed to Ropsten and verified on Etherscan, at https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x9C74b1FF49B1Ca900D283De895617bFA28E970ed#code (though note that I have used solc 0.4.25).

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy 1-2-3 guide to do this with solc 0.4.25? I used remix + metamask for this deployment.

Comment: To do **what** with solc 0.4.25? I used this compiler version just for personal convenience, and just for proving that it works. Shouldn't be different with any other version.

Comment: Can you please share the address of the deployed and verified contract?

Comment: I did, it is linkd in that comment above!

Comment: Did you use: 1. Remix 2. Injected Web3 for deployment? I see you set Optimization to Yes. I had it set to No.

Comment: I did it with a NodeJS script which used Etherscan API for contract verification. [This Etherscan Demo](https://etherscan.io/sourcecode-demo.html) uses the same API that I've used in my script.

Comment: sol-verifier ? https://medium.com/coinmonks/sol-verifier-an-npm-package-to-verify-smart-contracts-on-etherscan-bd4966eeab8a

Comment: No, I wrote Ethercan API and linked an example!

Comment: For some reason I can't see your links...until you send a follow up! Thanks a lot, I will look into it and let you know.

Comment: By looking at your demo page, I realize what I've been doing wrong the whole time: I was using the Bytecode instead of SOURCECODE on the etherscan verification page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great to hear that your problem was solved!

Answer (score 5):

I deployed the contract on the Kovan test net. Deployment versions same as you.

Everything worked properly. I see no reason for it not to work on Ropsten.

How did you deploy the contract? Maybe share the address to I can try to verify it.

Comment: Hi,I used remix with metamask to deploy. Here's the address.

Comment: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xe34eef9858cf00ce342f8f5d15f731ec91df1d8f